# org.opencv.core.Mat.nGetF causes segmentation fault __memmove_avx_unaligned_erms

Tags: java, opencv, segmentation-fault, glibc, onnx

Running a Java Rest API application with a ONNX machine learning model inside a container deployed on OpenShift. Day to day performance is fine for now, but for a new business case we want to increase the load.

Unfortunately increasing the load of the performance test throws segmentation faults at 'random' moments.
Sometimes the throughput is 150+ API calls per second before it breaks and sometimes <20 API calls per second before the crash.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fcd018b4023, pid=516, tid=615
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Red_Hat-11.0.19.0.7-1.el8_7) (11.0.19+7) (build 11.0.19+7-LTS)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Red_Hat-11.0.19.0.7-1.el8_7) (11.0.19+7-LTS, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, parallel gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0xd0023]  __memmove_avx_unaligned_erms+0x53
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: -Xlog:os=debug:file=os.txt:uptime,level,tags -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=85 app.jar

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007fcbdc003800):  JavaThread "http-nio-8080-exec-12" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=615, stack(0x00007fcc1f2f7000,0x00007fcc1f3f8000)]

Stack: [0x00007fcc1f2f7000,0x00007fcc1f3f8000],  sp=0x00007fcc1f3f3ea8,  free space=1011k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, A=aot compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libc.so.6+0xd0023]  __memmove_avx_unaligned_erms+0x53

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J 14698  org.opencv.core.Mat.nGetF(JIII[F)I (0 bytes) @ 0x00007fcce87f3d32 [0x00007fcce87f3cc0+0x0000000000000072]
```

The complete core-dump is available, but i am a bit lost where to search for the solution. Any help or tips are welcome.

Increased the memory and cpu limits in OpenShift and set the requested equal to the limits, to claim a Guaranteed Quality of Service, but the faults occurs before hitting the limits.

Edit:
After tweaking the Onnx settings (intra_op_num_threads and execution mode) and resources the segmentation faults occur less. But still once a week in one of the pods.